# Quartz Service - Simple Triggers

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I have a Quartz Job that I want to fire every minute.  The job itself contains logic to check to see if there is a process to run and if there is, this job could take 45 minutes to complete.

Using a Simple Trigger, will Quartz fire this job off every minute even if there is one already running?  Or if the interval is set to 1 minute, does that mean that Quartz will wait 1 minute after the job is done before it fires the next job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the trigger is set to fire every minute, it will fire every minute (and a new job instance will be created and invoked).

Unless the related job is marked @DisallowConcurrentExecution.